# regex match and replace in python

Tags: python, regex

I have one problem with regexp and match text file, I'm new into python.
My file looks like :

```
epg_slo3.txt:10346224:        Service_ID: 1 (0x0001)  [=  --> refers to PMT program_number]
epg_slo3.txt:10346236:            Start_time: 0xdce0112500 [= 2013-09-09 11:25:00 (UTC)]
epg_slo3.txt:10346237:            Duration: 0x0001000 [=  00:10:00 (UTC)]
epg_slo3.txt:10346246:                  event_name: "..©port"  -- Charset: ISO/IEC 8859  special table
```

What i need to to, I need something like this:

```
Service_ID: 1 (0x0001)  [=  --> refers to PMT program_number]: --> Program 1
Start_time: 0xdce0112500 [= 2013-09-09 11:25:00 (UTC)]: --> Start 2013-09-09 11:25:00 (UTC)
Duration: 0x0001000 [=  00:10:00 (UTC)] --> Duration 00:10:00 (UTC)
event_name: "..©port"  -- Charset: ISO/IEC 8859  --> Category ©port
```

My code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import codecs
import re

BLOCKSIZE = 1048576

with codecs.open('epg_slo10.txt', "r", "iso-8859-2") as sourceFile:
    with codecs.open('epg_slo.txt', "w", "utf-8") as targetFile:
        while True:
            contents = sourceFile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            if not contents:
                break
            targetFile.write(contents)


input_file  = open('epg_slo.txt', "r")
output_file = open('epg_slo_kategorije.txt', "w")

for line in input_file:
    line = line.replace("Service_ID:","Program")
    line = line.replace("Start_time:","Start")
    line = line.replace("event_name:","Title")
    output_file.write(line)
```

Can you help me with this,

thx for reading.
BR!

Comment: Are you trying just to get rid of all the `epg_slo3.txt:10346224:` like blocks?

Comment: Yes i wanna get rid of them all from file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `line = line.replace` in your code, add this line:

```
line = re.sub(r'^epg_slo3.txt:\d{8}:\s*','', line)
```

eg.
If

```
line = "epg_slo3.txt:10346224:        Service_ID: 1 (0x0001)  [=  --> refers to PMT program_number]"
```

then after calling `re.sub`:

```
line = "Service_ID: 1 (0x0001)  [=  --> refers to PMT program_number]"
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the `regex` given below with empty string ""

```
/^epg_slo3.txt:\d{8}:\s*/
```